# Cannot read property 'setTitle' of null, js engine: hermes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting the following error
[image]

while running my React native app.
Things I already tried:

1. devScripts/set-me-up.sh
2. deleting node_modules and installing them again
3. restarting server by reseting cache - npm start -- --reset-cache

but no success yet, any help would be great.

Comment: are you using setTitle in codebase?

Comment: no, there is no setTitle in codebase

Comment: go through this https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable/issues/304 I had similar issue

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

We have to restart with the command react-native run-android .It worked for me,there is no need to removing node modules or cache